# radio button selection based on update panel without postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a radio button when selecting it, dropdown list is getting visible. I want this process without postback and by using Update Panel.
After using radioRatingBool_CheckedChanged event, dropdown is visible but with postback. 
but i need it without postback.

here is radiobutton:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioRatingBool" Text="Bool" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="radioRatingBool_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

and here is function:

```
  protected void radioRatingBool_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (radioRatingBool.Checked == true)
                ddlRating.Visible = false;
            else
                ddlRating.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

please help me as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: Can you show your `HTML` including the `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: no i have not add update panel. this is what i m asking how to add it so that i would not get value with postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following :

1. Add the refernce of ASP.net Ajax assembly

then..

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>


<asp:UpdatePanel>
<contentTemplate>

Put your contents here..the radio button and drop down

<contentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Make sure AutoPostback is set to true

Comment: just 13 reputations :(

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your Radio Button and Dropdownlist inside the following html

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <!-- Your Controls... -->
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Check the following links for more information on how to use the UpdatePanel control and the ScriptManager control.

Update Panel : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx

Script Manager : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx

Update Panel Tutorial : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

Comment: so after adding my controls in it, when i change the check so it will not postback?

Comment: NO..it wont it matches only the portion which is inside update panel  and refreshes only that part of the page not entire page post back